# Programmatically add several buttons to an Excel worksheet with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I managed to programmatically add a button to a worksheet with an associated macro, but I'm having a problem when I try to add more buttons with associated macros, here is the code I use :

```
'Adding the first button
 With newWorkBook.Worksheets(1).Buttons
    .Add 350, 15, 173.25, 41.25
    .Caption = "Exporter"
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!export_Click_FCM"
 End With

 'Adding the second button
 With newWorkBook.Worksheets(1).Buttons
    .Add 350, 66.25, 173.25, 41.25
    .Caption = "Ouvrir le fichier Export"
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'!open_export_FCM"
 End With
```

When using this code, the first button appears with the caption of the second one and with its macro associated, and the second button appears with the default caption "button2" and with no macro associated, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first two lines of each block should be one:

```
With newWorkBook.Worksheets(1).Buttons.Add(350, 15, 173.25, 41.25)
```

so you get a reference to the added `Button`, not to the `Buttons` collection.